# Convert Text to Mtext and rearrange with QGIS

Tags: qgis, autocad, format

I have multiple names and parcel data in text form in AutoCAD.  I want to make them in the format as follows:

```
N/F
First and Last Name (Same as Shown)
T.A #Tax Number (Add T.A. # to each then keep the numbers the same after that)
```

I feel like there is a fast way I am missing instead of manually changing all of them by hand.

The text has no attributes with them that I need to keep.

I tried to export them to QGIS and have them all in but each text has multiple dots with information associated with it.  I need to only keep the top two in each circumstance and then flip them somehow.

[image]

Comment: are you reading the in the dwg in QGIS and converting to another format?

Comment: @Mapperz end goal is to have the drawing in autocad but I can easily convert it from QGIS to a Shapefile and bring it in that way.  I brought it from autocad to QGIS and am now looking at it within the QGIS program.